# How can I setvalue a select options in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

The problem is when I want to change the value it always shows me the first option.
This is my html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mt-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="operator-groups" formControlName="operators">
                            <option disabled selected value>Seleccione</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let operator of operators; let i = index;">{{operator.desc}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my component:

```
this._operatorgroups.index().subscribe(res => {
      let operators = <OperatorGroups[]>res;
      this.operators  = operators;
      this.registerForm.controls['operators'].setValue(res[1].desc);
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[selected]="condition that will result true for the option you want default"`

For example, if you want the 1st index (based on your code in the component), you'd do like:

```
<option *ngFor="let operator of operators; let i = index;" [selected] = "i==1">{{operator.desc}}</option>
```

Another example is, if you want lets say operator desc 'xyz' selected, you'd do like:

```
 <option *ngFor="let operator of operators; let i = index;" [selected] = "operator.desc == xyz">{{operator.desc}}</option>
```